# Why is my variable "undefined"?

Tags: lisp

Why is my variable `nodes` undefined in the vector-push-extend line?

```
(defun make_graph (strings)
  (defparameter nodes (make-array 0))
  (loop for x in strings do
       (vector-push-extend (make-instance 'node :data x) nodes))
n)
```

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that you should use `let` instead of `defparameter` to introduce your variable.  For instance:

```
(defun make_graph (strings)
  (let ((nodes (make-array 0)))
    (loop for x in strings do
          (vector-push-extend (make-instance 'node :data x) nodes))
    ;; your code says N here, but I assume that's a typo...
    nodes))
```

The `defparameter` form is useful for creating "special" variables, which are somewhat similar to global variables in other programming languages.    (There are some differences, e.g., the special variables introduced by `defparameter` aren't exactly global---instead, they are dynamically scoped, and can be `let` bound, etc...)

At any rate, the `let` form will instead create a local variable.

Comment: I would never use `defparameter` in this way, but I'm curious about why OP's code didn't work.  I would have thought that it would.

Comment: @Mars, Rainer Joswig's answer explains it.  In short, variables declared that way aren't defined yet at compile time, which is when the compiler emits the warning.

Answer (score 4):

`DEFPARAMETER` is used at toplevel to define global *special* variables.

Toplevel:

```
(defparameter *foo* 42)
```

Still at toplevel, because forms inside `PROGN` are still at toplevel (by definition):

```
(progn
  (defparameter *foo* 42)
  (defparameter *bar* 32))
```

Not at toplevel:

```
(defun baz ()
  (defparameter *foo* 42))
```

Above last form is not recognized by the compiler as a variable declaration. But when one calls `(baz)` and the function is running, the variable is defined and initialized.

A non-toplevel use of DEFPARAMETER will not be recognized by the compiler, but at runtime it will create a special global variable.

```
(defun make_graph (strings)
  (defparameter nodes (make-array 0))
  (loop for x in strings do
        (vector-push-extend (make-instance 'node :data x) nodes))
  n)
```

The compiler warns:

```
;;;*** Warning in MAKE_GRAPH: NODES assumed special
;;;*** Warning in MAKE_GRAPH: N assumed special
```

Thus in above code, the compiler does not recognize `nodes` as a defined variable, if it wasn't defined somewhere else already. The *use* of `nodes` in the function creates a warning.

Still the code might work, since at runtime the variable is created and initialized - but for every function invocation. Over and over. This compiler also assumes that `nodes` is just this: some kind of special variable. Still I would not count on it for all compilers.

`n` is also not defined anywhere.

**Notes**:

- the correct way to introduce local lexical variables is to use `LET` and `LET*` (and other binding forms)
- use `DEFPARAMETER` as a toplevel form. It is unusual when it's not a toplevel form. Typically the author makes a mistake then.